# BufferedInputStream is not empty, but no data available to read

Tags: java

I faced this kind of behavior first time. I have method that gets file from SFTP server, and returns it byte[] representation. But i cant get proper rersult (it is always byte[0]).
InputStream is not empty, BufferedInputStream too. BufferedInputStream buf[] contains array on approximately 8kb(i have small picture on the other side).
But

> bis.available()

returns always 0; 
What have i missed?

```
public static byte[] downloadFileasBytes(String remoteFilePath){
    StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

    try {
        manager.init();

        // Create remote file object
        FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());
        try(InputStream is = remoteFile.getContent().getInputStream();){
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            byte[] byterepr = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read(byterepr);

            return byterepr;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Logger.getLogger(SFTPUtility.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SFTPUtility.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }

}
```

#### UPD

Okay i will try not to do such mistake in future.
For now i resolved this problem in this way.

```
try(InputStream is = remoteFile.getContent().getInputStream();BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
            IOUtil.copy(bis, baos);
return baos.toByteArray();
```

}

Comment: "Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next caller of a method for this input stream." Don't count on it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the javadoc for [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) (emphasis mine), you should not rely on `available()`:

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream ...
>
> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, **many will not**. **It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer**
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

Comment: but how can i define result array size? There is no other available data that i can use

Comment: A common practice is to use a fixed array size, then read in a loop from the stream into that array, until the read() operation returns -1, which means end of stream. In many cases you will not know in advance how many bytes can be read form the stream, unless the data size is actually given as the first data in the stream.

Comment: The [FileContent.getSize()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileContent.html#getSize()) method can be used to get the byte size of the remote file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FileContent.getSize()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileContent.html#getSize()) to get the size of the remote file in bytes.

Note that the documentation of [FileContent.getInputStream()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileContent.html#getInputStream()) says:

> The input stream is buffered, so there is no need to wrap it in a BufferedInputStream.

So you could use something like this:

```
InputStream is = remoteFile.getContent().getInputStream();    
try {
    byte[] byterepr = new byte[remoteFile.getContent().getSize()];
    is.read(byterepr);
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: oh, thanx for mention about buffers!